# Is it okay to use slang-swear words in questions as an example?

Tags: discussion, support, etiquette

When I was asking a question today, I had to write an example and it had a swear word that sounds like "duck". But I hesitated to write it in the question, so I had to explain that word other ways. I hesitate to use it even in this question -ironically.

Since English is not my first language it's hard to explain things like that to other people.

In questions is it okay to use words like those?

Comment: Even when discussing code to censor swear words, you can always use something else as an example; this doesn't technically change the question. "I want to find and replace all instances of the word goose" is the same question as "I want to find and replace all instances of the word duck". What you use as your list of forbidden words in your actual code makes no difference.

Comment: Is there a non-zero chance that the use of swear words could cause a page of the site to get stopped by a filter if someone is browsing at work? I'm guessing 'no' but it's the only other potential problem I can think of with doing this.

Comment: I mean, technically there is a rule against this: *Inappropriate language or attention. Avoid vulgar terms and anything sexually suggestive. Also, this is not a dating site.* https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice But the context seems more about not harassing other users, not about words you're trying to filter out of your input.

Comment: Beware that profanity filters are discussed to death on SO - there is a good chance that your question will show no research/instant duplicate... I don't really see other reasons to use such words in a question (short of "these @#@#@ SO people closed my previous question @#@# them" - but that is fluff to simply be removed).

Comment: @BSMP: Well, yes, considering it says "**Don't be a jerk.**" in bold. But then again, some people equate having a word filter to being a jerk - to those who want to be able to swear their heads off, anyway.

Comment: Just use "duck." Everyone who has ever used autocorrect will know what you meant, but no one will be able to flag it.

Comment: Two tears in a bucket.  Duck it.

Comment: @Cody Gray: "I'm flagging this because the word 'duck' is obviously a misspelling of a bad word."

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IMO I don't see anything wrong with it — otherwise we wouldn't be able to accept questions about profanity filters — but some people have been known to switch their brains to "profanity filter mode", performing blind searches for swear words and proceeding to flag ***every single search result*** as "rude or abusive" without regard for any context whatsoever. These flags will cause unwarranted downvotes on your posts, although the downvotes will be removed when the flags are declined by a moderator.

If you want to be *really* safe, you can substitute another word for the sake of illustration. (Provided the substitute doesn't cause *other* problems with your code...)